# Finding sum of power $5$ in polynomial

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Consider the function $f(x)=x^4-2x^3-x^2+17x+6$ and another function $g(x)=x^5-3x^4+22x^2-18x-2$ and $f(x)=0$ has a roots $x_{1},x_{2},x_{3},x_{4}.$ Then $\sum^{4}_{k=1}g(x_{k})$ is

what i try

$x^4-2x^3-x^2+17x+6=(x-x_{1})(x-x_{2})(x-x_{3})(x-x_{4})$

$\displaystyle \sum x_{1}=2\;\;, \sum x_{1}x_{2}=-1\;\;,\sum x_{1}x_{2}x_{3}=-17$ and $\displaystyle \prod x_{1}=6$

$\displaystyle \sum^{4}_{k=1}g(x_{k})=\sum^{4}_{k=1}(x_{k})^5-3\sum^{4}_{k=1}(x_{k})^4+22\sum^{4}_{k=1}(x_{k})^2-18\sum^{4}_{k=1}(x_{k})-2\sum^{4}_{k=1}1$

$\displaystyle \sum^{4}_{k=1}g(x_{k}) = \sum^{4}_{k=1}(x_{k})^5-3\sum^{4}_{k=1}(x_{k})^4+22(4+2)-18(2)-2(4)$

How do i solve it Help me please

Comment: I think you are already on the right track. First, please adjust your notation in the third row. I think you mean $\sum x_k=2$ and similarly for the other equations. In the last equation, start at the back. You already know the $\sum x_k$ term. For the $\sum x_k^2$ term you can use $(\sum x_k)^2=\sum x_k^2 + 2 \sum_{k \neq l}x_kx_l$. Similarly but with more algegra required you can compute the remaining terms.

Comment: Your task is simplified somewhat if you also use the fact that
$$g(x)-(x-1)f(x)=-x^3+4x^2-7x+4.$$ That way you don't have to go higher than $\sum_{k=1}^4x_k^3$. Anyway, you may want to use [Newton's identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities), but the sum of third powers in terms of the elementary symmetric polynomials may be simpler to work out by hand.

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen did not know How to proceed further, please explain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT...Writing $$S_n=\sum_{i=1}^4x^n_i$$
You have $$S_0=4, S_1=2, S_2=6$$ And also $$S_{-1}=\frac{\Sigma\alpha\beta\gamma}{\alpha\beta\gamma\delta}=-\frac{17}{6}$$

Then, you can obtain $S_3$ from the equation itself because $$S_3-2S_2-S_1+17S_0+6S_{-1}=0$$
and then obtain $S_4$ from $$S_4-2S_3-S_2+17S_1+6S_0=0$$
and then obtain $S_5$ from $$S_5-2S_4-S_3+17S_2+6S_1=0$$

Alternatively, following Jyrki Lahtonen's suggestion, you sum the identity he gives so that $$\sum g(x_i)-0=-S_3+4S_2-7S_1+4S_0$$